# Migrate closed question

Tags: support, closed-questions, migration, moderator-tools

Is there a way to migrate a question that is already closed *without* first reopening it and closing again as off-topic to migrate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### No.

[image]

Comment: I didn't think so. I was going to `[tag:feature-request]` this, but wasn't sure that there wasn't something I was overlooking.

Comment: I think that would be a rather pointless feature.. It's not *that* hard to just reopen it and migrate it.

Comment: @Seth Agreed, just thought it would be cleaner not to have to do that.

Comment: @Jim Yes it would be cleaner, but a lot of work for the team.. Most migrations need a mod anyway. *most*.